# Make images loop over with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a little client slide with `javascript`. 
What i have achieved so far is to move the images om button click.
Below is the code

**HTML**

```
<div class="client-slide">
    <img src="images/oma.png">
    <img src="images/pz.png">
    <img src="images/tata.png">
    <img src="images/mik.png">
    <img src="images/may.png">
    <img src="images/dang.png">
    <img src="images/vita.png">
    <img src="images/cap.png">
    <img src="images/cla.png">
    <img src="images/int.png">
</div>
<ul class="slideBtn">
    <li><div class="leftButton"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></div></li>
    <li><div class="rightButton"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></div></li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScirpt**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.leftButton').click(function() {
        $('.client-slide').animate({
            'marginLeft' : "-=100px"
        });
    });
    $('.rightButton').click(function() {
        $('.client-slide').animate({
            'marginLeft' : "+=100px"
        });
    });
});
```

Above code work when i click on the button. I want such that when i click on the button, the image in position one goes to the last position there by creating an infinite loop.

Thanks.

Comment: I once created a slider as an answer on stackoverflow. Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39673540/an-infinite-carousel-with-vanilla-javascript/39678409#39678409

Comment: I suggest you create a fiddle or code snippet including the css

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service. There are hundreds of carousel/slider scripts and tutorials all over the web you could study to figure this out

Comment: You can easily use **Owl Carousel** or anything else..

Comment: @charlietfl this i know already. I wouldn't ask if i have not tried already.

Comment: Tried what ? I see absolutely no attempt shown to do what you are asking. Rather it seems you just want someone to code a carousel for you when you could simply get a working one yourself

Comment: @pedram i know about owl carousel. That's an option. Just trying to figure this out.

Comment: @charlietfl tried with a `for` loop. would update now.

Comment: @diagold So better provide a live demo of what you tried so far

Comment: **[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users?s=1|81.5729)**